# I'm stuck in a teleporting loop. What can I do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I set a command block to `/tp`. It was supposed to activate only if you had 0 time left, and to activate the command block with a hopper clock to keep giving it power.

But it is not checking if you have 0 time left, so it keeps teleporting me. I can't get close enough to the command block to break it, so I'm stuck in a neverending teleport loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are running on a Mac with Time Machine (or equivalent) - then the easiest way to fix this is to restore from the last working backup. You can find the saved game data in /Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/minecraft.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you are running this world on a multiplayer server, you can disable command blocks completely via the [server properties](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server.properties#Minecraft_server_properties). Shut down the server, open `server.properties` with a text editor of your choice and set

```
enable-command-block = false
```

This disables all command blocks. Join the game, destroy the command block in question and reenable them afterwards.

In singleplayer, it's a bit more complicated. You have to open the world as a multiplayer* server. Open `server.properties` and set

```
level-name = [relative path to your savegame]
```

e.g. `saves/world` (use `/` to divide folders).

---

*If you haven't run a multiplayer server yet, you can download the server.jar (or server.exe) from the [Minecraft website](https://minecraft.net/download) and save it wherever you want. Run it once to generate some files, including `server.properties` and a savegame called `world`.

To join your own server, connect to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in Minecraft.

Comment: I think that this solution works best if you're already running a server.

Comment: I'm a little surprised there isn't a game rule for this, that you have to do it through server properties.

Answer (score 23):

For situations like this, an external world-editing tool is best. Find the command block, and delete it.

A common one is MCEdit, which is available here: http://www.mcedit.net/

---

As @MrLemon mentions, you could be running a multiplayer server, in which case MCEdit is a bad idea -- the download time of a 60GB map is non-negligible. In that case, follow his answer.

Answer (score 13):

```
/fill X1 Y1 Z1 X2 Y2 Z2 minecraft:air
```

Fill in X Y and Z with the approximate coordinates of the command block, and you've replaced a region around the command block with air.

Answer (score 10):

Another alternative is to change the command using [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac). This tool is much less powerful than MCEdit, but it easier to use and does work for this case. This works largely the same as [my answer here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/230213/74333), so feel free to reference that in case something is unclear. The crucial thing is that you have to remember either where your command block is located, or any semi-unique part of your command.

Command Blocks are [Tile/Block Entities](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tile_Entity), since a regular data value is not enough to store all information about them. Instead, they have NBT data similar to entities, which are detailed on the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Block_entity_format). In particular, command blocks ("Control") have a `Command` entry. NBTExplorer is able to read the region format and search for a Tile Entity with a specific entry.

1. Close Minecraft. Open up the program and select *File > Open Minecraft Save Folder*. You will get a list of folders corresponding to your worlds. Open up the world you want to search, and select the "Region" folder.
2. Use *Search > Find* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) to look for *Name: Command* and *Value: [your command snippet]* until you have found the command block in question (This is described in greater detail in the [answer linked above](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/208780/how-do-i-locate-command-blocks/230213#230213)).
3. Double-Click the *Command* entry and change it's value to either fix the command directly (for example, turn `\kill @e[type=!player]` into `\kill @e[type=!Player]`) or just enter something harmless (e.g. leave it empty).
4. Press the save button and close NBTExplorer. When you open up your world in Minecraft, the command should be changed.

Answer (score 7):

Destroy the block using a world editor, then use a command block to comparator for the test part with the `/testfor` command.

You want the comparator to go to a command block that just puts up a message to find out if the `/testfor` command and comparator are working properly. Do not start the `/tp` command until you have confirmed that the first two parts are working in conjunction with each other properly.

Answer (score 4):

If the command block is not at the spawn; type `/kill`.

But if one is at spawn just look down real quick and break it if you can.

Comment: You can't. It kills you too fast.

Answer (score 4):

You could change the gamerule  `randomTickSpeed` to 0.

Something similar happened to me: I was being teleported 5 blocks up with a command block in a Minecart on a powered activator rail. They activate every 4 game ticks.

Comment: `randomTickSpeed` has absolutely nothing to do with activating command blocks. It affects only the random ticks responsible for growing plants and such.

Answer (score 3):

For Bedrock Edition,  just type the following command in chat:

```
/gamerule commandBlocksEnabled false
```

This will disable command blocks. Then type this when you are in a safe position:

```
/gamerule commandBlocksEnabled true
```

This will re-enable command blocks.

Comment: Works on Nintendo Switch version.

Comment: This is a [tag:minecraft-java-edition] question. Posting answers that only apply to a completely different game is unhelpful.

Comment: @pppery - Not really. This answer is useful to users [finding this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYL94.png) through Google, [regardless of how it is tagged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9PWq.png). Plus, the answer was posted before the java/bedrock tag split - when this question was just tagged [minecraft] and applied to both versions of the game. There was always going to be some overlap - not every question can or should be split cleanly down the middle.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is go into the chat, and use the set block command to set the command block to a block of air.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 figure out the coordinates of the command block that is teleporting you

Step 2 do the following: /fill (x coordinate of the command block) (y coordinate of the command block) (z coordinate of the command block) (x coordinate of the command block) (y coordinate of the command block) (z coordinate of the command block) minecraft:air

For example, if the command block is at 34 55 -2769 do /fill 34 55 -2768 34 55 -2768 minecraft:air

Comment: This is a similar answer to the answer Rainbow Dash gave two years ago.  Also, if you are only trying to replace one block, the `setblock` command does not require you enter the same coordinates twice.

Answer (score -3):

You could turn to Creative mode and fly so it can't reach you if it is below you as a pressure plate... I don't really know if it'll work, but you can try it! ^_^

Comment: Please only answer if you have an answer, otherwise comment. This solution does not work.

Answer (score -7):

If all else fails, use /summon PrimedTnt to blow up the command block.

Comment: This doesn't work.  Command blocks have an incredibly high blast resistance, and won't be blown up by a single piece of TNT.  The best that can be hoped for is to blow up the clock, but there are even clocks that can't be blown up (like a 20 Hz clock).