# How to hover minecraft using command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm doing a command block creation and I need to know how to "hover" on block over the ground beneath me in survival if tried putting this is my current command but I just keeps me at the same y axis

/tp @a[score_Hover1_min=1] ~ 57 ~

So I could use some help I guess this is a pretty hard question but does anybody know an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure how to completely hover, but ~ 57 ~ will teleport you to the absolute y 57. If you put another ~ in front of the y number, as in ~ ~57 ~, it will teleport you 57 blocks straight up relative to your current position.

Comment: This is possible in the 1.9 snapshots, but please specify which game version. If you're looking for 1.8, it's not possible.

Comment: What @2xedo wrote is correct, but he omitted a clear warning: Don't put `~ ~57 ~` unless you have a way of breaking out of your teleporting loop (cf. [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170185/im-stuck-in-a-teleporting-loop-what-can-i-do)).

Comment: Sorry I'm in Minecraft 1.8 the I never update until it's at least to its 9th update I'm in 1.8.3 though I'm planning on updating soon but I'll update to 1.9 I I have to in order to get out my creation

Comment: I find that dousing the place with water is usually sufficient to destroy the redstone and deactivate the loop. If not, I will invite a friend over using LAN.

Answer (score 2):

You can place a block under the player 20 times a second. To do this create a command block tick clock that executes the command:

`execute @e[name=<player name>,type=Player] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:sandstone`

Comment: Wouldn't a barrier be a better idea as this would just look like a sandstone block constantly under the player and it would be indestructible. Furthermore the block of sandstone has a 50/50 chance of still being on that spot after the player moves. Also also the blocks would replace terrain which is not desirable on any mode. This answer could work it just needs more finesse.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in the 1.9 snapshots.

The command is

> /effect @a levitation 1000000 255 true

This will produce a hovering effect. You can't go up and down, but it achieves what you've requested.

Also, the question is worded oddly, and doesn't completely make sense.

If you want a version that allows you to traverse down the Y axis, then try this

> /effect @a levitation 1000000 252 true

This gives the player a slight downward movement. If you want to go up, try

> /effect @a levitation 1000000 2 true

This is all I can help you with unless you specify in more detail what you want.

Note: If you want it to be like creative mode flight, I can put something together for you.

Comment: Ok thanks one problem is that I don't really use snapshots until the full update comes out beacuase I'm afraid that my worlds might get corrupted but if it means getting the new arrows and all those sick commands I'm up for it and what I'm I really afraid of mojang has done this for almost 10 updates

Comment: 1.9 has now come out

Comment: I'm a bit late but, might I enquire how I would get "creative mode flight" with command blocks? I've spent a few hours combining jump with slow falling effects, but just can't seem to figure out a balance that provides creative like behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this but I will assume it works in almost all versions.

Set up a clock circuit with a command block attached and put this in it

```
/tp <Name Of Player> ~ ~<blocksToBeLifted> ~
```

Replace  with the height above the ground you want the player to levitate. Make sure you test it first because the clock circuit might go to fast and lift the player up blocks faster than they fall (so they will continuously go up)

In short this command constantly teleports the player upwards. Just remember you need to have a ~ before the amount of blocks you want the player to be lifted. To stop the player from floating just stop the clock attached to the command block.

Sorry if I didn't answer your question correctly, didn't really understand it properly!

Comment: Nope. That'll shoot you upwards (if gravity isn't fast enough).