# Console Message: Set score of cat for player [player guid] to #

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, server-administration

I have a server which I rented for my daughter and her friends. When you go into a certain area of the map, the server console will display a message like this about 20 times per second, and it's causing performance issues on the server.

```
3:02:29 PM @:: Set score of cat for player 0f98d479-2149-473a-bb1f-3291bcd6819b to 2]
```

I'm pretty sure that my daughter's friend created something in creative mode that is causing the problem, but I'm not sure which object it is.

Any way to isolate what's causing the problem and fix it?

Thanks,

Joshua

Comment: While a largely different question, the answers [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170185/im-stuck-in-a-teleporting-loop-what-can-i-do) might help you, since you'll probably want to disable the offending command block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a command block is constantly running `/scoreboard players set @p cat 2`. What you can do to stop this is find the command block and either destroy it, or set the O/X button to X. Both of these will stop the server console printing, but that simple command shouldn't cause that much lag. My guess is that someone used a fill clock, and not a repeating command block. If you see a contraption like the below, destroy the redstone blocks on the ends; this should solve the problem.

[image]

PS: In the event that you cannot find any command blocks, or can otherwise not deactivate them, It may be helpful to use a world editor, such as MCEdit, to remove the command blocks.

Comment: Thank you for helping out.

I went to the server and turned off Command Blocks and the error went away.

I then drew borders around the affected areas on the map and was able to isolate the problem to a small building the player made in the wilderness way outside of town with commandblocks like you showed.  We destroyed those and the problem went away.

Thanks for the help!