# My Minecraft world wont load because of a particle command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was editing a nuclear fusion reactor simulator that I made, and I added a command:

```
/particle explosion 2 62 84 2 62 84 100000 10 normal <PLAYER NAME>
```

And had it repeat and it didn't need redstone. When I exited the command block console, it crashed my game. So I launched Minecraft again, tried to open the game, and the second it opened, it crashed. How can I fix this?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, but [some of the answers to this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170185/im-stuck-in-a-teleporting-loop-what-can-i-do) might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using mcedit or nbtExplorer, to remove the command block. Mcedit will make it easier to find the command block, but it is also a bigger program to download.

http://www.mcedit.net/

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac

In mcedit, you can edit the world directly kind of like you do when playing the game. You just find the block then destroy it. With nbtExplorer, you would open the world file, find the correct region and chunk, then the proper command block uner tile entities. You could remove it from there.

Comment: How, exactly, would you use MCEdit or nbtExplorer to accomplish this goal?

Comment: In mcedit, you can edit the world directly kind of like you do when playing the game. You just find the block then destroy it. With nbtExplorer, you would open the world file, find the correct region and chunk, then the proper command block uner tile entities. You could remove it from there.