# Minecraft 1.10.2 command block crash

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built a command block with some command and I can't play the world anymore. Everytime I try to start the world it crashes and turn off Minecraft. Is there some way how to remove that command block without starting the world?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm stuck in a teleporting loop. What can I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170185/im-stuck-in-a-teleporting-loop-what-can-i-do)

Comment: You may get a better answer if you can upload that world so others can try to load it and possibly diagnose the problem.

Comment: but its on tekit with some more mods ...

Comment: If you have mods and your world crashes, we can't help. We don't do tech support for modded Minecraft.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tech support for modded Minecraft. We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt your command block is causing the world to crash.  Here is a solution to use an external application to set the command block's command value to nothing. I recommend making a backup copy of the world before attempting this in case something goes wrong.  I have used NBTExplorer to modify many worlds without problems.

[Go download NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac). It's free.  It is a small editor for NBT files.  It is useful for many things in Minecraft.

Open it.  Click on the world name you want to search. (In my case BigRed)

[image: NBTExplorer]

Open Search menu, click Find menu.

Check the Name check box and type `Command` in the search field, type the command or part of the command in the value field and click <kbd>Find</kbd>.

[image: NBTExplorer2]

It will find a command block and you will see something like this:

[image: NBTExplorer3]

It shows the command in the command block.  If it is not the correct command block, open Search menu and click Find Next.  Continue this until you find the correct command block.

Make sure you don't have the world open in minecraft and double click the line containing Command and set the command value to nothing.  Click File -> Save before trying to play the world.

When you open that command block in game, the command portion will be blank.

Comment: i cant find that ... that program just search for 1 hour and when i cancel it that program crash ... or "End of results"
its not there...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMQUD.png

Comment: I was unaware that you were using mods.  Mods are outside the scope of my answer.  Mods may be the reason your world is crashing.  Mods may be the reason the application is hanging as well.  You could try searching just the region folder of that world.

Comment: no its  100% because that comand block ...

Comment: i write this in that command block ... 
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ mob_spawner 0 replace {SpawnData:{id:skeleton,HandItems:[{Count:1,id:bow,tag:{ench:[{id:34,lvl:3},{id:48,lvl:5},{id:49,lvl:2},{id:50,lvl:1},{id:51,lvl:1},{id:71,lvl:1}]}},{}],ArmorItems:[{Count:1,id:diamond_boots},{Count:1,id:diamond_leggings},{Count:1,id:diamond_chestplate},{Count:1,id:diamond_helmet}],HandDropChances:[0.5f,0.0f],ArmorDropChances:[0.3f,0.3f,0.3f,0.3f]},MaxNearbyEntities:20,Delay:10,MinSpawnDelay:10,MaxSpawnDelay:10,RequiredPlayerRange:16} 
and after i press button on it it crash ....

Comment: I just ran your command in vanilla 1.10.2 Minecraft without a problem.    I doubt the command block is the problem.  Most likely, it is the spawner that it produced.  I suspect it is a conflict with one of the mods.

Comment: i will try save it somehow ... ty for help and your time :3