# How do I turn off a command that's on repeat on Switch Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I put a command block that would teleport "@p" so when i get close it teleports me back to another place, its Always Active and its a Repeat Command Block, I've tried lots of commands but none work, I've been trying for hours

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334102/how-do-you-add-nbt-tags-to-commands-in-minecraft-pocket-bedrock-edition)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm stuck in a teleporting loop. What can I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170185/im-stuck-in-a-teleporting-loop-what-can-i-do)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of either of the linked questions (especially the first).  Solutions that apply to the Java Edition for this type of problem do not necessarily apply to the Bedrock Edition.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable command blocks temporarily using the command, `/gamerule commandBlocksEnabled false`. You can then re-enable them by changing `false` to `true`.

Comment: thank you, it really helped me, i thought i lost my world, i wonder why this wasn't in any video!!

Comment: @user232135 Don't forget you can accept the answer by clicking the check on it, notifying that this answer worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable command blocks via the settings menu, fix it up, then re-enable command blocks.

> Go into your world settings. Scroll down to the cheats section and you should see "Command Blocks enabled" or something like that. Flick that off and the command block should stop. If you don't want your chat to be spammed like that, type `/gamerule commandblockoutput false`. That will disable the output of the commands. After you fix your command block, you can go back into your settings and turn the "Command Blocks Enabled" setting back on.

Source: [darthvader1925's answer at "What can I do to get out of a command block teleporting loop?"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/378577/28088)

Answer (score 0):

You could [set](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/setblock) the block coordinate it's in to air, or [fill](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/fill) a region it's in to air.

Comment: ive tried that and it said it filled it but i still can't get close