# What can I do to get out of a command block teleporting loop?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I accidentally forgot that I was using a repeating command block, and teleported myself to the front of my house. Now I can't move because my clock is fast and on the lower level. There is another repeating command block spamming gold blocks and I can’t turn it off.

I’m surprised my game isn’t lagging, because it’s been going on for 20 minutes while the text to speech for chat is saying over and over “you have been teleported to ...”

How can I stop this loop?

Answer (score 2):

Go into your world settings. Scroll down to the cheats section and you should see "Command Blocks enabled" or something like that. Flick that off and the command block should stop. If you don't want your chat to be spammed like that, type `/gamerule commandblockoutput false`. That will disable the output of the commands. After you fix your command block, you can go back into your settings and turn the "Command Blocks Enabled" setting back on.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
/gamerule commandblocksenabled false
```

Then fix the loop, and run:

```
/gamerule commandblocksenabled true
```

to turn command blocks back on.