# How to stop a /kill loop

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

On my Minecraft server one of my admins placed a command block "/execute @e run say HEY SAV URE GAYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY" and made it always active. I cannot figure out how to stop the command block. How do I end the command block loop?

Comment: Do you mean /kill @a? And by always fire you mean it's always active right?

Comment: yes sorta  the always is right but the /exacute is making every entitie in the game say a thing

Comment: It sounds like you are the server owner, isnt there something you could do to disable command blocks on the server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm stuck in a teleporting loop. What can I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170185/im-stuck-in-a-teleporting-loop-what-can-i-do)

Comment: What now, does the command block kill or say things? Your title disagrees with your description. Also, if you're a normal player without any permissions, you can't do anything against command blocks, only turn chat invisible or not play there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the server owner, stop the server and disable command blocks by setting "enable-command-block=true" to "enable-command-block=false" in the **server.properties** file (located in your main server directory where the server jar is).