# Delete all command blocks without opening minecraft world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a minecraft world and messed a command up so whenever I open the world i can't do anything, due to huge lag. How can I remove or disable these command blocks without deleting the other world data?

Comment: Solved the problem by deleting a chunk in the region files

Comment: There are less destructive methods: [I'm stuck in a teleporting loop. What can I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170185/im-stuck-in-a-teleporting-loop-what-can-i-do)

Comment: I couldn't use MCEdit, due to a PySide error, but will look into the NBT tool for next time, cheers