# How to stop a runaway structure block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a tileable redstone contraption, made a **structure** block to make creating copies of it easier, and to make tiling it easier, included the structure block that loads the next one inside the saved structure. Except I didn't spot the adjacent block powers up as soon as the structure is placed, and next time I triggered 'load', I had my contraptions tiled to the horizon.

1. How to stop it? Chasing the front is futile as as soon as the new chunks load it starts growing out of my reach.
2. How to clean up the mess it left behind, several thousands of copies of the contraption?
3. Any smart way to prevent it in the future other than make absolutely sure there is no, and won't be any redstone power around the newly spawned block?

In particular, note these are *structure*, not *command* blocks and they spawn in hundreds, so classic solutions targetting a single misbehaving command block don't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm stuck in a teleporting loop. What can I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170185/im-stuck-in-a-teleporting-loop-what-can-i-do)

Comment: @pppery: this seems to work only on command blocks, not structure blocks.

Comment: Ugh, this is a nightmare scenario....  I haven't explored structure blocks yet, so just a comment.  Can you replace all of them with air once your chunk loading stops?

Comment: @John: I believe I found a solution to problem 1. Save an empty structure (just an air block) under the same name. Still, #2, no clue short of restoring a backup, and no 'systemic' solution for #3 other than just being damn cautious.

Comment: On a related note, have three self-triggering structure blocks with different offsets and orientations in the structure, the fork bomb quickly swallows a sizable bit of terrain, then crashes the server. With two, it doesn't crash, just spreads over a huge swath of land at alarming pace, bringing mspt to a crawl.

Comment: This reminds me of playing with fork() and exec() on unix systems 30+ years ago....

Comment: In particular: Disabling command blocks is useless. McEdit supports Minecraft versions 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 1.10, 1.11 and Forge 1.7, so antiques. `/fill X1 Y1 Z1 X2 Y2 Z2 minecraft:air` would require me to know the location of the last block, which is now in a random location good 200 blocks away (and if I move towards it it will start moving away). NBTExplorer: search for "Structure" "spam" with the name given yields nothing. And I have hundreds of structure blocks, most but not all from the 'explosion', indistinguishable unless I open every single one.  `/gamerule randomTickSpeed to 0` - srsly?

Comment: I can't have retracted my close vote (I have less than 3,000 rep, so what I actually did was cast a close **flag**, which was automatically marked helpful when the first real close vote was cast.) In any case, this question [was reviewed as "leave open" by a moderator](/review/close/285354), so is no longer in danger of being closed.