# Ways to turn of a repeating_cb set to tp you away from it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I just added a repeating command block to an adventure map(1.15.2) I've been working on for awhile. It's purpose was to detect a falling player and then to tp them approximately 300 blocks away. I got distracted and ended up turning it on with a command along the lines of
"execute if @p at @p run tp 20 70 200"
This causes me to tp to the location whenever the block region containing the command block is loaded.

My question is has anyone got any ideas of possible ways to solve this?

I know the general location but cannot use the fill function as the blocks aren't loaded. And states this when executed

Gamerule commandblockoutput false doesn't help

And it registers me in spectator mode and still tp back.

Comment: Which edition of Minecraft are you playing?

Comment: is "then to them" a typo for 'then tp them"?

Comment: Or if you're on a server, [I'm stuck in a teleporting loop. What can I do?](/questions/170185). Or, if you prefer to edit the save, [How do I stop a looping command block in Minecraft for Windows 10?](/questions/360646)

Comment: I should of mentioned I'm playing on Java Edition there is only gamerule commandblockoutput which isn't helping. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm stuck in a teleporting loop. What can I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170185/im-stuck-in-a-teleporting-loop-what-can-i-do)

Answer (score 1):

To solve my problem I traveled to the edge of the unloaded section.  Activated a repeating cb with a fill command set to replace with air. Opened my map to lan and used the second player to trigger the tp and load the chunks.

Another method I used was to travel again to the edge of the unloaded area. Use the fill command to add activator rails and a minecaft with command block and pushed this into the unloaded area with a fill command active.

I added both methods as they both worked and many people may not use the lsn feature.