# fix command issues

Tags: minecraft-commands

so i tried to build a station that teleports you away when you come close, but now it repeats teleporting me to a specific place and i cant move from there. I'm also not able to destroy the command block because it is to far away. I wanted to ask if there was a way to destroy the command Block with a command from the distance  so i could get away from the place it teleports me to. Game Version: 1.12.2 (i cant use 1.16 commands)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm stuck in a teleporting loop. What can I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170185/im-stuck-in-a-teleporting-loop-what-can-i-do)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into spectator mode.
2. Go to the command block and find it's position by going onto the debug screen.
3. Finally, set the block to air.

1. `/gamemode spectator`
    2. <kbd>f3</kbd>
    3. `/setblock (block's position) air`

Comment: I'd recommend you answer this on the other post because if this works it's by far the best solution