# Remove too much sand from The End

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I accidentally ran a sand duper in my world for about an hour, and I can't figure out how to fix it. I can't type any commands because my game freezes the second I enter the end.

---

How do I remove sand from the end?

Comment: What is a "sand duper"? Since you "ran" it, it could be a command, so could you post that command here?

Comment: This sounds _very like_ https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170185/im-stuck-in-a-teleporting-loop-what-can-i-do

Comment: @TimmyJim No, it's a different question. Sand dupers rely on exploting bugs in Minecraft's handling of falling blocks, and don't use commands. I also find this question to be clear enough, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

Put a command block (repeat, unconditional, always active) in the spawn chunks that run the following:

```
kill @e[type=falling_block]
```

Hopefully, if you go into the end, all of the sand gets killed.

Comment: If this doesn't work, you may have to use a third party nbt editor.

Comment: I managed to fix it by using a world editor.